# Why does this haskell code failed

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

First of all I don't exactly understand the error message, so I can only use a ambiguous question title

This code is from Chapter 8 of Channel 9 lecture about *programming in haskell*
[image]

I was trying to run this code by GHC and I wrote

```
-- Functional parsing library from chapter 13 of Programming in Haskell,
-- Graham Hutton, Cambridge University Press, 2016.

module Parsing (module Parsing, module Control.Applicative) where
import Data.Typeable
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Char

-- Basic definitions

newtype Parser a = P (String -> [(a,String)])

parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a,String)]
parse (P p) inp = p inp

item :: Parser Char
item = P (\inp -> case inp of
                     []     -> []
                     (x:xs) -> [(x,xs)])

-- Sequencing parsers

instance Functor Parser where
   -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> Parser a -> Parser b
   fmap g p = P (\inp -> case parse p inp of
                            []        -> []
                            [(v,out)] -> [(g v, out)])

instance Applicative Parser where
   -- pure :: a -> Parser a
   pure v = P (\inp -> [(v,inp)])

   -- <*> :: Parser (a -> b) -> Parser a -> Parser b
   pg <*> px = P (\inp -> case parse pg inp of
                             []        -> []
                             [(g,out)] -> parse (fmap g px) out)

instance Monad Parser where
   -- (>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
   p >>= f = P (\inp -> case parse p inp of
                           []        -> []
                           [(v,out)] -> parse (f v) out)

-- Making choices

instance Alternative Parser where
   -- empty :: Parser a
   empty = P (\inp -> [])

   -- (<|>) :: Parser a -> Parser a -> Parser a
   p <|> q = P (\inp -> case parse p inp of
                           []        -> parse q inp
                           [(v,out)] -> [(v,out)])

return' :: a -> Parser a
return' v = \inp -> [(v, inp)]

p' :: Parser (Char, Char)
p' = do 
    x <- item
    item
    y <- item
    return' (x, y)

main = print (p' "123")
```

The code consists a lot of code I copied from given demo code Parsing.hs, and a `p'` function same as the slide

Running this code causes an error

```
4.hs:63:15: error:
? Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char] -> a0’
              with actual type ‘Parser (Char, Char)’
? The function ‘p'’ is applied to one argument,
  but its type ‘Parser (Char, Char)’ has none
  In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘(p' "123")’
  In the expression: print (p' "123")
```

It seems there's some thing wrong with the type, and I tried

```
main = print (item "123")
```

neither did it work

However when I simply remove the definition of `Parser`, and replaced them with definition mentioned in previous slide

```
type Parser a = String -> [(a, String)]

item :: Parser Char
item = \inp -> case inp of
                    [] -> []
                    (x:xs) -> [(x,xs)]

return' :: a -> Parser a
return' v = \inp -> [(v, inp)]

main = print (item "123")
```

and it just worked with output `[('1',"23")]`, and I got confused here.

BTW, I found that in the comment section a leomm asked the same question as me, and he figured this out later. However I just can't work this out.

Comment: `item` is a `Parser`. I think you need to `parse item "123"` rather than just do `item "123"`.

Comment: `p'` is of the `Parser (Char,Char)` type, which is a `newtype`, so it is considered a separate type from the function type you expect, even it is isomorphic to it. You can use `parse p'` to recover the function you want, as MathematicalOrchid pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`newtype` requires a constructor, `type` does not. If we want to replace `type` by `newtype`, we need to add a constructor, `P` for example, to any usage of our `Parser` type; in order to resolve `Parser`, we implement `parse`.

Starting from your second example code, we will get

```
newtype Parser a = P (String -> [(a, String)])

parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a,String)]
parse (P p) inp = p inp 

item :: Parser Char
item = P (\inp -> case inp of
                [] -> []
                (x:xs) -> [(x,xs)])

main = print (parse item "12345")
```

Now let's implement your special parser `p`. In order to use `do`, we implement the Monad instance.

We add to our code:

```
instance Monad Parser where
  -- (>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
  p >>= f = P (\inp -> case parse p inp of
                       []        -> []
                       [(v,out)] -> parse (f v) out)
  -- return :: a -> Parser a
  return v = P (\inp -> [(v, inp)])

p :: Parser (Char, Char)
p = do  
  x <- item
  item
  y <- item
  return (x, y)
```

Our `main` command becomes:

```
main = print (parse p "12345")
```

In my opinion, the error messages in ghc are rather extensive, but one has to read very carefully; one also has to be very careful with using data types.